# How to scale my subviews in UIScrollView simultaneously？

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

Basically, my view hierarchy is as below:

```
UIWindow (level 1)
   |--UIScrollView (level 2)
           |--single UIView (level 3)
                |-- Multiple subviews (level 4)
```

When the user pinches at one subview in level 4, the App will

1. scale all subviews in level 4 to size of (1024, 748), i.e. full fill the whole iPad screen, my App is always works in Landscape mode.
2. display the subview (level 4) which the user pinch at as the current content.

I try to add below code in the pinch gesture handling procedure to enlarge the UIView, it didn't work, it only enlarge the UIView frame, but the level 4 subviews are not scaled at all.

the reason I add the level 3 UIView is that I want all the Level 4 subviews to be scaled automatically when I scale level 3 UIView, so I don't need to scale these subview one by one.
Now I was confused, can this work? or do I need to scale all level 4 subview one by one manually?

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchTap:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

NSLog(@"handle tap");
CGRect oldFrame = self.levelThreeUIView.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    self.levelThreeUIView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldFrame.size.width, 748);


}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to set the `autoResizing` property of each of your subviews. This basically resizes the subviews if the parent view size changes. Easiest way to set this property is to goto Interface Builder & select your view & do this -

[image]

You see the `Autosizing` box right, for each of the subviews select all four & inner auto resizing options. on the right i.e. in Example, Xcode shows you how the view will resize based on your settings.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late ... but just in case anyone else stumbles into this ...

you need not resize the third level view. instead, you must set the UIScrollView's contentSize to the size of the third level view,

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.levelThreeUIView.frame.size;
```

set the scroll view's delegate to your controller

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

and put

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.levelThreeUIView;
}
```

the content will be scaled automatically when the user pinches

note that the frames of every subview are not changing, just the scale at which they are displayed